Why does request.COOKIES periodically return an empty dict?
I set a cookie in my view like so:
response.set_cookie(
    'cookie_name',
    'true',
    max_age=100000
 )

The cookie sets ok, and is viewable in dev tools. I have a tag which checks for a specific cookie on every page load:
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_cookie_status(context):
    request = context['request']
    print(request.COOKIES)

Around 40% of the time, this prints an empty dictionary and I have absolutely no idea why. As I said above, Django picks up no cookies at all, but the loaded page has all of the expected cookies present. Is there any common reason why this would occur?
